# Is a symmetric linear transformation necessarily invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L: V \rightarrow V$ be a symmetric linear transformation. Does this imply that $L$ is invertible?

Comment: Take $L=0$ the zero transformation.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $L$ be the trivial endomorphism. That is, $L=0$.

Comment: But is ($L$ orthogonal $\Rightarrow$ L is invertible) correct?

Comment: Yes, $\det(L)=\pm 1$ for orthogonal transformations, because of $LL^t=Id$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, take a diagonal transformation $L$ with at least one zero on the diagonal. Then $L$ is symmetric and  $\det(L)=0$.